# Checking if Luks header is damaged

Tags: mdadm, luks

Is there any way to check if the Luks container header is damaged? My luks container is refusing to be opened with its keyfile, saying `No key available with this pass-phrase.`

History of what happened:

I was working with mdadm raid5 trying to increase the disk sizes of a 3 component array. I think I encountered a bug in mdadm software and was forced to close the luks container and reassemble the array. The configuration of `md0` is this at the moment:

```
        Version : 0.90
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 3907023872 (3726.03 GiB 4000.79 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953511936 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 2
          State : clean, degraded 
     Chunk Size : 64K

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       9        2        0      active sync   /dev/md2
   1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2       0        0        2      removed
```

Un-important info removed.

`/dev/md2/` is a linear mdadm array made of up 1 (2TB) disk. `sdc1` is a 4TB disk. Only 2TB of it is used by this array, as displayed by `Used Dev Size`.

Problems arose when I expanded `md2` linear array to 4TB using another disk, and tried to grow `md0` to the new component size. It complained that `0.90` metadata only supported 2TB component disks and displayed `Used Dev Size: -1`, quick google search revealed that it wasn't good. My mistake was then to shrink `md2` back to its 1 disk size (2TB) this signalled to `md0` that the device failed and put `md0` into `FAILED` mode.

To add that component back to the array without resync I had to stop and reassemble the array. Since then the luks container won't open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For closure, I might as well post what the issue was: Turns out mdadm by default creates arrays with a different version than the one I had, so in the process of re-assembling it, it overwrote some of the backup positions on the disks, one of these backup positions co-insided with the luks header, wiping it out. Never did manage to recover the data from that. Lesson learned.